# Deserialize JsonArray with kotlinx serialization

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

I have the following Json object:

```
{
  "List":[
      "string1",
      "string2",
      "string3",
      "..."
   ]
}
```

This deserializes into a JsonArray containing JsonLiterals.
When deserializing this and trying to iterate over it I get an error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonLiteral cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

What would be the standard way to achieve something like that?

Comment: Show us your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that you are using the latest version of `kotlinx.serialization`.
A comment in the implementation of `JsonLiteral` states that

> `JsonLiteral` is deprecated for public use and no longer available. Please use `JsonPrimitive` instead

`JsonPrimitive` has the `isString` method to check if it is a string and you can then access it using its `content` method.

Comment: I am using version 1.3.3

Comment: Good, then you should use `JsonPrimitive` instead

Comment: this acutally pointed me into the right direction, thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help! You can mark the answer as the solution or suggest improvements for when others come looking with the same question as you

Comment: yes I will post/edit the answer tomorrow.

Comment: You can also use `buildList {}` to create `whiteList`

Comment: alright, after some delay here's the code  that i came up with in the end:

    `val jsonElement = model?.parameters?.get("whitelist")
        jsonElement as List<*>
        val whitelist = ArrayList<String>()
        jsonElement.jsonArray.forEach { element ->
            if (element.jsonPrimitive.isString) {
                whitelist.add(element.jsonPrimitive.content)
           }
    }`

Comment: oh thx, will have a look at that `buildList {}`

Comment: @Halex can you please take a look on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73064940/11560810)